# How do I recover from Selenium error on Meteor?

Tags: node.js, selenium, meteor, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code, called on Meteor server (for those who don't know Meteor, it runs on top of Node.js) from a method:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

function getPage(page) {

    driver = driver || new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

    driver.get(page).catch(function(error){
        throw new Meteor.Error("Can't get page " + page)
    })
}
```

Those familiar with Meteor know that it should normally propagate Meteor.Error to the client. Instead, Selenium catches my error and exits with code 1, resulting in server restart:

```
W20160712-12:49:40.093(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20160712-12:49:40.104(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/irinaapex/irina/meteor/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:654
W20160712-12:49:40.104(-7)? (STDERR)     throw error;
W20160712-12:49:40.105(-7)? (STDERR)     ^
W20160712-12:49:40.105(-7)? (STDERR) Error: [Can't get page i]
W20160712-12:49:40.118(-7)? (STDERR)     at imports/somethingSel.js:35:15
W20160712-12:49:40.120(-7)? (STDERR)     at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/irinaapex/irina/meteor/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
W20160712-12:49:40.121(-7)? (STDERR)     at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/irinaapex/irina/meteor/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
W20160712-12:49:40.123(-7)? (STDERR)     at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/irinaapex/irina/meteor/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
W20160712-12:49:40.124(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/irinaapex/irina/meteor/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27
W20160712-12:49:40.132(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/irinaapex/irina/meteor/selenium/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
W20160712-12:49:40.134(-7)? (STDERR)     at /Users/irinaapex/.meteor/packages/promise/.0.8.3-beta.9.1fbal0n++os+web.browser+web.cordova/npm/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:32:39
=> Exited with code: 1
W20160712-12:49:53.217(-7)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on port 49906
=> Meteor server restarted
```

It seems that for me to successfully pass error message to client, I need to prevent Selenium from intercepting the error. How do I do that?

Comment: is there an exception you can handle?

Comment: Yes, but I need to throw Meteor.Error, because that results in Meteor propagating the reject to the client. Workarounds can be found, but this is how errors are normally handled in Meteor.

Answer (score 0):

2 things going on here I believe:

1) the call to the driver to get the page is asynchronous, so you should really wrap this into a `Meteor.wrapAsync()` call.

2) If you do this, I would think the the Error will be sent synchroneously to the return value of the call. Or you can catch it and there re throw the error as a `Meteor.error()`.